# How to start an android activity only for a specific user in firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, android-activity, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am using firebase and android along with user authentication.

I want an activity to start only for one specific user with email id - someemail@gmail.com.

my code is:

```
System.out.println("uid "+auth.getCurrentUser().getEmail());
if(auth.getCurrentUser().getEmail().equals("someemail@gmail.com")){
    Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, AdminActivity.class);
    System.out.println("uid1 "+auth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
else {
    Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
```

Even though I log in with someemail@gmail.com, it starts the `MainActivity.class` instead of `AdminActivity.class`

```
System.out.println("uid "+auth.getCurrentUser().getEmail());
```

prints someemail@gmail.com but it doesn't work in the if condition.

I am new to android and firebase, please help.

Comment: to compare a string, try using `auth.getCurrentUser().getEmail().equals("someemail@gmail.com")`, otherwise it compares the reference and not the string itself

Comment: no, it still doesn't work.

Comment: Give it a try to TextUtils.equals(auth.getCurrentUser().getEmail(), "youremail@domain.com")

Comment: @EmreAktürk yes it works! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are doing string comparison using "=="

`if(auth.getCurrentUser().getEmail()=="someemail@gmail.com")`

Strings are compared using equals() method

`if(auth.getCurrentUser().getEmail().equals("someemail@gmail.com"))`

Comment: I tried this, but it doesn't work. @kunwar97